# Finding out installed Metro applications on a machine

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am trying to write a piece of code in C# to find all installed Metro Applications on a machine. I came across the following post [Get a list of metro apps and launch them in Windows 8 using PowerShell](http://powertoe.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/get-a-list-of-metro-apps-and-launch-them-in-windows-8-using-powershell/)  which explains obtaining this from the system registry. Is this the only reliable way to obtain the list? Does anyone know of any other ways? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this from *within* a Metro application itself? Because if so, it feels like the sort of thing that wouldn't be possible when running within the sandboxed environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish I could comment...Is this an option?

```
IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = 
        (IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package>)packageManager.FindPackagesForUser("");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx

Comment: The above code is not working for Windows 8 app, it's throwing "Access is denied" exception, while initializing `PackageManager` object. It will work only in desktop or console app.

Comment: My bad, clearly says "You can not use this class in a Windows Store app."

Comment: I get the following error when I compile the project "The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'" . Any ideas why I am seeing this?

Answer (score 7):

Thanks everyone! For the PackageManager code to work, I had to do the following

1) Add the following to .csproj.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetPlatformVersion>8.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

2) Add a reference to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd

After doing the above, I was able to list all the metro packages.

Comment: So eventually did it work inside a metro App or you were able to iterate the in a non-metro App?

Comment: I was getting Yam's error in the comment to Braim's answer above, but added <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/> to the .csproj file inside the <ItemGroup> tags. This fixed the error and the project built successfully. The project is a console app.

Comment: Thanks! On my computer, the reference in step 2 was at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Annotated\Windows.winmd`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't iterate through all packages installed in PC in WinRT app. It's possible in desktop and console app. See these MSDN threads for more info.

[How to get all Metro apps list in Metro App?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/62a8b86e-34ce-40c2-939c-8fb4a5dd0acb/how-to-get-all-metro-apps-list-in-metro-app)

[How do I get all Metro style apps list in my Metro App?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e06a5538-11ca-4705-9824-fc694f11b650/how-do-i-get-all-metro-style-apps-list-in-my-metro-app)

To perform the same [here's code.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240969.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's wondering how to get the `packageManager` variable in the accepted answer you need to do the following:

```
Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager packageManager = new Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager();
```

I guess this belongs to a comment, but I don't have enough reputation, sorry.