# Getting the list of installed windows store apps

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, desktop-application

There are ways to get the list of installed applications that come in Add/Remove Programs in ControlPanel.
But I want to get the list of installed applications from windows store too. I have not got anything so far.
Is there any way to get the list of applications installed from windows store?

Comment: There is definitely a way, as CCleaner and IOBit Uninstaller do it. I'd assume they're calling some commands that you'd typically call from a PowerShell window.

Comment: In C# or C++ or .NET or as any desktop application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackagesforuser) will help to get the list of metro applications;
with reference to [this exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178990/finding-out-installed-metro-applications-on-a-machine), [`FindPackages` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240969.aspx) with example:

```bat
IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package> packages = 
    (IEnumerable<Windows.ApplicationModel.Package>)packageManager
        .FindPackagesForUser("");
```

1. To use this class, open `.csproj`, and change target platform version to `8.0`:

   1. Right-click on the project name in Solution Explorer
   2. Select *Unload the Project* and it will become like `projectname(unavailable)`
   3. Right-click → Select: *Edit `.csproj`*
   4. Load the project again
2. Add a reference to `system.runtime`; if you don't find it, add a reference to its `.dll` from:

   ```bat
   %WinDir%\Microsoft.Net\assembly
   ```
3. Add a reference to:

   ```bat
   %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You can run these commands on a powershell window and get the list of installed apps on a Windows 10 machine

```
Get-AppxPackage | ft Name, PackageFullName -AutoSize
```

If you want to get a list of all the apps of all the users, then use the below command.

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | ft Name, PackageFullName -AutoSize
```