# How can I detect an UWP application (Skype) is installed in C#?

Tags: c#, skype

I have a C# program that will call skype for a given phone number or Skype ID.

```
string input;
//...
string uriSkype = $"Skype:{input}?call";
Process p = Process.Start(uriSkype);
if (p != null)
{
    p.WaitForExit();
    p.Close();
}
```

The code does work, for both UWP Skype or desktop Skype.
But I want to direct a message to user if Skype (neither windows store version or desktop version) is not install.

I can detect desktop version by looking at registry:

```
RegistryKey SoftwareKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software");
if (SoftwareKey != null)
{
    RegistryKey SkypeKey = SoftwareKey.OpenSubKey("Skype");
    if (SkypeKey != null)
    {
        RegistryKey PhoneKey = SkypeKey.OpenSubKey("Phone");
        if (PhoneKey != null)
        {
            object objSkypePath = PhoneKey.GetValue("SkypePath");
            if (objSkypePath != null)
            {
                // here I know the path of skype.exe is installed.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above way can find if skype.exe is installed.

What I want to know is: how can I correctly detect if UWP version of Skype installed?

Comment: You could look in the registry to see if the Skype protocol is installed - i.e. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\skype` contains a `URL Protocol` entry.

Comment: What exactly is your question? In one sentence you say "The code does work, for both UWP Skype or desktop Skype." and in the other "how can I correctly detect if no any version of Skype installed?".
Is it working or not? Do you just want to show a Popup for the user "Skype is not installed"?

Comment: Consider using Skype API instead of going the registry way

Comment: I would like to show a messagebox and direct to skype's homepage if no UWP/desktop skype is installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a not-so-clean answer, using powershell commands, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196430/getting-the-list-of-installed-windows-store-apps) and [this msdn article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/).

I need powershell 2.0 installed, and add a reference to `System.Management.Automation.dll` from windows sdk.

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // get the installed apps list
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-AppxPackage | ft Name, PackageFullName -AutoSize");
    // format output to a string
    PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("Out-String");
    // invoke execution on the pipeline (collecting output)
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
    // loop through each output object item
    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        string strOut = outputItem.ToString();
        if (strOut.Contains("Microsoft.SkypeApp"))
        {
            // do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```